# Delete item from listview when the item is clicked

Tags: java, android, listview, android-studio

I currently have this code to display chosen items in a listview:

```
public class DisplayOrder extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_order);
    bar();

    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnHome);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(DisplayOrder.this, Options.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);

        }
    });
}

private void bar() {


    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewDisplay);

    List<String> itemsOrdered = new ArrayList<String>();


    for (Map.Entry<Item, Integer> entry : Datastore.currentTable.getOrder().getItems().entrySet()) {
        itemsOrdered.add((entry.getKey().name) + " x " + String.valueOf(entry.getValue()) + " £" + (entry.getKey().price * entry.getValue()));
    }


    // This is the array adapter, it takes the context of the activity as a
    // first parameter, the type of list view as a second parameter and your
    // array as a third parameter.
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(), R.layout.activity_display_order, R.id.textView8, itemsOrdered);

    lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
}
}
```

What i want to do is, when I click one of the items, for it to be deleted but Im not sure how to do that. Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should detect when you click in each item of `ListView` by `setOnItemClickListener`.
Then inside this method, just delete the list datasource and notifyDataSetChanged

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView < ? > parent, View view,int position, long id) {

        itemsOrdered.remove(position); // remove item at index in list datasource
        arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // call it for refresh ListView

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "remove item at " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to override the listener “setOnItemClickListener” like this:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
    int position, long id) {
    itemsOrdered.remove(item);
    arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

  }
});
```

This code removes the ítem from the list, but you have to notify the change to the adapter. When the adapter is notified the listview is updated.